# Run EditNTS in Google Collab... ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, simplification

I am trying to run a Text Simplification algorithm called EditNTS. I got it to run successfully locally on my machine by removing the cuda() method. However I am trying to run it on google Collab so I can take advantage of the GPU. However I am getting the error:

```
File "/content/drive/My Drive/EditNTS-master/data.py", line 193, in __init__
    self.df = pd.read_pickle(data_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py", line 182, in read_pickle
    return pickle.load(f)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
```

I tried `!pip install pickle5` and importing `pickle5 as pickle` within *data.py* but I still get the same error.

Does anyone know the fix to this? Here is the link to the google drive all you have to do is download my edits to the code and run it within google collab like so.

[image: Google Collab]

P.S main.py returns the editNTS model but I cannot find a function within the code which will allow me to use the editNTS model to predict each simple sentence from a complicated document. If you can help me with this that would be *super* helpful. Thank you guys in advance.

Here is the link to the google drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1R3ZpC_P-k9NOruiKhwsTRi_nlTG5yfjw?usp=sharing

For local: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Wmmkb60fzui1YZUJpHXFbdXsJGRBPQXB?usp=sharing